# Android toolbar issues

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm having a very strange issue using MaterialDesign toolbar and I haven't been able to figure out what's causing it.

I have a toolbar with a custom menu icons which I use in different layouts using `<include>` I wanted to use the toolbar in another layout without all the icons and menus so I included this in the xml:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
```

But the toolbar that shows when on this activity view is the same one I use across other activities. I even tried using a different id name but it still uses the other toolbar and not the one I have included. 
The other issue is that, I want to use material design scrolling by using the coordinator layout. While the scrolling works on every other layout, it doesn't work on this particular one when I have the toolbar set. If I remove the toolbar then the scroll works for the view below it. The scroll property `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"`on both the toolbar and the view below it. Here's the full code for this layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <Yourtime.NonSwipeableViewpager
      android:id="@+id/profileviewpager"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
      android:id="@+id/appbar">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
    <FrameLayout
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:id="@+id/profile_container"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_tabs_height"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/profiletabs" />
  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I will really appreciate if someone can help with either of the questions.

Comment: have you set your toolbar as actionbar in second activity

Comment: I've set the toolbar using SetActionBar(Toolbar toolbar)

Comment: @AhmedMujtaba so you want different toolbars for different activity ?

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan That's precisely what \i want.

Comment: if you try to reuse the same for the all the activities you fail correct ? Try to use two different toolbars and implement it wherever you want. let me know if i'm wrong